# How to use SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM and SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 in same computer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following version of SQL Server 2008 R2 in my computer.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (Intel X86)   Apr  2 2010 15:53:02   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X86> (Build 7600: )
```

Now i want to install the SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 to my computer. But i can not remove the previous version. because some of my clients still use the that version.

I wont to use both of this versions. Is it possible to use 2 different versions of SQL Server in same computer ? What is the way to keep these 2 versions ?

Comment: try using virtual machine ?? that allows you to install other version in same computer?

Comment: @Vijaykumar Hadalgi - Any other way without using virtual machine ?

Comment: can you tell me whats the use of putting 2 different versions on the same computer,when not jus try to use a updated version?

Comment: I am doing some projects for clients. some of my clients use that RTM version and some are use R2 SP2 version. If i use only RTM version i can not restore the backups which are got from SP2 version. If i use only R2 SP2 version some my clients (who are using RTM version) can not restore the backups which are get from SP2 version. Simply backups get from SP2 version not supported for RTM version. that is why i want to use both versions.

Comment: Just install a second, separate **instance** of SQL Server on your machine. That's what **instances** are for, after all !

Comment: @marc_s - Please can u give me the necessary steps. I downloaded SQLServer2008R2SP2-KB2630458-x86-ENU.exe from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30437 and RTM version is already installed in my computer.

Comment: Just **run the install** and then choose to install a **named instance** and give your new installation a meaningful **instance name**

Comment: @marc_s - But when i try to install the downloaded copy it shows heading like update SQL server. therefore i abort the installation. Is this updating is ok or do i download a wrong copy ?

Comment: You've downloaded **just the Service Pack** - that's **NOT** a full version of SQL Server! That's why it will only update your existing installation.

Comment: @marc_s - Can u give me the link for full version please.

Comment: Take your CD/DVD that I'm sure you have and use thta !

Comment: @marc_s - No i don't have. I thought i can download it form the internet. any help ?

Comment: The full versions of SQL Server aren't just available freely for download - they need to be properly licensed, otherwise you're committing software piracy. If you have properly licensed SQL Server, then you'll either have a physical media (CD/DVD), or you will have a MSDN subscriber account where you can download the necessary software from.